# On Table alignment

Tags: tables

I have the following tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline, justification=centering, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{amsmath,ragged2e} % <-- new
\usepackage{interval,pbox}

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\hyphenation{bur-kina}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[p]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\caption{Summary statistics}
\label{tab:sumstat}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{d{1.5}}}
\toprule \toprule

Variables       & \mc{Obs.} &\mc{Mean}  &\mc{S.D.}  &\mc{Min.}  &\mc{Max.} \\ 
\midrule
HP                  & 326,463       & 0.841         & 0.365         & \mc{0}        & \mc{1}\\
CAF                & 326,463        & 0.006         & 2.213         & -7.446            & 4.996\\
GLOB                & 326,463       & 0.255         & 0.436         & \mc{0}        & \mc{1}\\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item[]{\textit{Notes}:My notes}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it, I have the following result:

[image]

I cannot figure out why the three columns highlighted in red are not aligned.

Any support on this?

Comment: What you mean with `326,463`? Are this two numbers or one number with three integers and three decimals or one number with 6 integers where comma is used as group separator?

Comment: It is three hundreds thousands and something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is content of your second column. I suspect, that you like to achieve something like this:

[image]

But I'm not sure (see my comment below your question).

By use of the `tabularray` and `siunitx` package the MWE, which reproduce above table, is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         table-format=-1.3
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Summary statistics},
  label = {tab:sumstat},
remark{Note} = {My notes}
                ]{
    l S[table-format=6.0] *{4}{S} 
                 }
   \toprule
Variables   & {{{Obs.}}} & {{{Mean}}} & {{{S.D.}}} & {{{Min.}}} & {{{Max.}}}    \\
    \midrule 
HP          & 326 463    & 0.841      & 0.365      & {{{0}}}    & {{{1}}}       \\
CAF         & 326 463    & 0.006      & 2.213      & -7.446     & 4.996         \\
GLOB        & 326 463    & 0.255      & 0.436      & {{{0}}}    & {{{1}}}       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exploit `siunitx` instead of `dcolumn`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline, justification=centering, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\sisetup{
  group-separator={,},
  %table-format=1.3,
  %table-space-text-post=***, 
  %table-number-alignment =center
}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[p]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}

\caption{Summary statistics}
\label{tab:sumstat}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Variables & {Obs.} & {Mean} & {S.D.} & {Min.} & {Max.} \\ 
\midrule
HP   & 326,463 & 0.841 & 0.365 &  0     & 1 \\
CAF  & 326,463 & 0.006 & 2.213 & -7.446 & 4.996 \\
GLOB & 326,463 & 0.255 & 0.436 &  0     & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item[]{\textit{Notes}: My notes}
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I commented out three settings in `\sisetup` that really don't belong there.